# What problems might I face keeping a directory under git and svn control?

Tags: git, svn

I've been running into problems with `git-svn`, and in searching for a solution I stumbled across [this page](http://coliveira.net/software/using-git-and-svn-at-the-same-time/), in which the author decided to simply use both git and svn, since they both hold all of their important information in .git and .svn directories.

I suspect the main problem with this type of workflow is coordinating between svn and git, and  making sure that the updates/commits happen in lockstep. So I thought of having a workflow along these lines:

```
git init
svn checkout https://svn.myplace.com
add .svn to .gitignore
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial Commit'
git checkout -b working
```

hack, commit, hack, commit, hack, commit

```
git checkout master
svn update
git add .
git commit -m 'svn update'
git merge working master
fix possible conflicts
svn commit
```

wash, rinse repeat

If I stick to this workflow (and of course using other fancy git features), are there any issues that might bite me, or does this seem pretty reasonable (based on the fact that the repos here at work are all Subversion, and I'm not in charge of those decisions)?

Comment: What kind of problems are you having with `git-svn`?

Comment: @bdonlan, Our repository structure is kinda bizarre (to me) here at work - multiple unrelated (other than by division) projects are stored under the same repo. I can access our training repo just fine, but `git-svn` will only clone up to revno 3 from my area repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a similar approach (as detailed [here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/02/03/branch-per-feature-how-i-manage-subversion-with-git-branches/)) for about 5 months without any real problems.

It does require some discipline, but if something bad happens you can always ditch the git repository and start again.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, and a that link was a great resource. And for me, where several unrelated projects are added to the same repository, the extra administrative costs have nothing on not having to pull/push the whole repo every time.